# Return function

Tags: function, return

i want more understand about return function. Is return function the function have a return value,what is that mean ? Plis give example and explanation about function have a return value and not have a return value.

Answer (score 0):

`return` is a statement for functions, so let's say you have a bit of code like `print(myFunction())`.
myFunction's return value is what print is printing.

so if I have

```py
# define function
def myFunction():

    # this gives "Hello World" to whatever runs it
    return "Hello World"

# put the return value in a variable
a = myFunction()

# print the variable data
print( a )
```

when you run `a = myFunction` the function is `return`ing "Hello World" and storing it in the variable `a`. then you're just printing value of `a`.

Comment: Oo so that mean can use that function for a  variabel for a second time cause that storing value at a variabel is that right ?

Comment: Yep, it just puts what the function creates in whatever calls it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way,

Sometimes you want your function to do something for example add something to a variable:

```
a = 1

def add_1(x):
    x += 1

# This would add 1 to the variable a. No return needed.

add_1(a)

# Now a is 2.
```

but sometimes you would want a function to return something that you could work with. For example printing it or saving it to another variable:

```
a = 1

def add_1(x):
    return x + 1

b = add_1(a)

# The function returns a + 1, which is 2, and saves it to the variable b.

print (add_1(b))

# The function prints the returned value of b + 1, which is 3 and would print 3.
```

Hopefully this was helpful.